# Excel - Keeping Original Cell Value with VLookup and Iferror function

Tags: microsoft-excel, vlookup

I am stuck with a Vlookup formula I'm working with. I need to apply the vlookup formula to a whole column, but here's the catch - I need the formula to not do anything if it returns an error. There are values in the cells that I will need to keep if Vlookup doesn't work. So I don't want "N/A", and I can't have it return blank if it wasn't blank previously, I need it to keep the original cell value, or leave it blank if it was previously blank and Vlookup doesn't work on it. Does anyone know how to do this?

Here's my vlookup: VLOOKUP(B8,'Pd  Rollers'!$F$9:$J$427,3,FALSE)

I've tried several variations on these formulas and have had no luck getting it to work properly:

=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(B8,'Pd  Rollers'!$F$9:$J$427,3,FALSE),cell("content"))

IF(error=VLOOKUP(C3,'Pd  Rollers'!$F$9:$J$427,4,FALSE),CELL("contents"),VLOOKUP(C3,'Pd  Rollers'!$F$9:$J$427,4,FALSE))

Any help is appreciated, thank you!

Comment: You can either have the value or the formula but not both.  Best practice is to have a separate column with your user inputed values and another the IFERROR formula that returns the user inputed value when error.

Comment: Welcome to Super User! A cell cannot hold both a value and a formula simultaneously; it's one or the other. It sounds like you may want to do the lookup in a separate column first and then merge the results with your original data.

Answer (score -1):

You are on track with the first example, the `=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(B8,'Pd Rollers'!$F$9:$J$427,3,FALSE),cell("content"))` (except it should be `contents` (plural) vs. `content`).

There are two things you must do to make it work. First is to add a reference to the `CELL()` function. Say your formula is in A1. Then that component would be `CELL("contents`,A1)`.

But what makes that work is to enable iterative calculation so that the circularity of that does not lead to the calculation failing and "0" being placed in the cell. Do this in the general settings for Excel:  `File|Options` selecting the `Formulas` area and immediately at the top, on the right, checking the checkbox for `Enable iterative calculation` and then setting `Maximum Iterations` to "1" ("1" in particular, not just something small or close... exactly "1").

Still, you must run the formula so it has an acceptable starting value otherwise whatever pops up upon entering the formula will be the conserved value. So basically, run the lookup successfully, then send it into the wild for yourself or your users to run it on whatever values they need.

Any success will be conserved until a new use of the cell's formula produces a new success. So, conserved until something new appropriate is produced which will then itself be conserved until... and so on.

(Note that this works in YOUR scenario in which you have a formula in the cell to start with, to wit, the lookup formula. If you had a value (what Excel calls a "constant") like "blue" in the cell, not a formula, it would not be conserved by the above. But then you'd have the components of a simple `IFFERROR()` function and no need for these kinds of hoops to be jumped through so it doesn't matter too much.)

Of course, changing a basic setting in this manner is fairly major for most folks, and would often see the changing back when done with the spreadsheet forgotten with knock-on effects. I do not know off-hand whether this setting is available for changing via VBA, but if it is, a macro that runs to set it when opening the file and one that runs to reset it when closing the file would be good things to add. If available to set, those macros should be very simple to write. It might even be available via the macro recorder and so take no real knowledge of VBA past making the macros `On Open` and `On Close`.

Tested the macro recorder and this is its output for resetting my setting after having changed it to test the end formula from yours:

```
    Sub Macro1()
    '
    ' Macro1 Macro
    '
    
    '
        With Application
            .Iteration = False
            .MaxIterations = 100
        End With
    End Sub
```

Clearly, setting it would just use `True` for `.Iteration` and `1` for `.MaxIterations`.